# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'prime' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I get this error

> UnboundLocalError : local variable 'prime' referenced before assignment

when using this code to see if a number is prime. How do I fix it?

```
import math 

def is_prime(n):
    if n == 2:
        prime = 1
    if n % 2 == 0 or n <= 1:
        prime = 0

    sqr = int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1

    for divisor in range(3, sqr, 2):
        if n % divisor == 0:
            prime = 0

    if prime != 0:
        print("Prime")
    if prime == 0:
        print("Not prime")


is_prime(int(input("Number? ")))
```

Comment: All your assignments to `prime` are in conditions. If none of the conditions succeed, you won't set it.

Comment: You should initialize it with a default value at the beginning.

Comment: BTW, you should use `True` and `False` rather than `1` and `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If none of the conditions succeed, you never set `prime`. You can break out of the `for` loop when you find a divisor, and use `else:` to set `prime` if that never happens.

Also, you'll give the wrong answer for `2`. First you set `prime = 1`, but then `n % 2 == 0` will succeed, so you'll set it to `0` there. Use `elif` for the second test, so it's skipped in that case. And you can use `else:` for the rest, so you don't waste time with the loop for smaller numbers.

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n == 2:
        prime = True
    elif n % 2 == 0 or n <= 1:
        prime = False
    else:
        sqr = int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1

        for divisor in range(3, sqr, 2):
            if n % divisor == 0:
                prime = False
                break
        else: 
            prime = True

    if prime:
        print("Prime")
    else:
        print("Not prime")
```